# yopMail asking for Captcha when run on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, captcha, katalon-studio

I have a set of automation scripts running locally from Katalon (you can consider it as selenium webdriver scripts).

It goes to [yopMail](https://www.yopmail.com) (webmail client) where emails are checked. Once it is run locally it goes smoothly. Once it runs from a Jenkins server it prompts for Captcha code. Is there a solution on how to overcome this?

Or why does it prompt for it when running from Jenkins? Thanks for any hints.

[image: captcha]

[image: captcha2]